# Search a file in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, find, logging, catalina

I need to search a file in unix which starts with "catalina"

```
 find ... what to be used effectively -name, -exec ? Whats the expression
```

Also I need to show few files at a time, then show some more. There are huge set of log files in there. I know there is some expression, but forgot...

Comment: Do you want to search for a file - or search within those files matching *catalina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find /path/to/search/in -name 'catalina*'`

Use `iname` to match case-insensitively.

To not be overwhelmed with a long list of files, filter through `less` (append `|less`). You can also use `more` instead of `less`.

Comment: Still standard way is to use `more`, not `less`.

Comment: @pooh: Well, "standard way" is always open to debate. Only Linux, `less` is pretty much the standard, but to each his own :-).

Comment: there's **unix** in the topic, that's why first i think of POSIX `more`.

Comment: @pooh: OK, you have a point. But then, most Unices have a port of `less`. Might not be the standard, though. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If catalina is the file name, then use

```
find -name 'catalina*'
```

If catalina is the first word contained in the file, then use

```
find -type f | xargs head -v -n 1 | grep -B 1 -A 1 -e '^catalina'
```

Comment: Note that you can do this without `find`, at least in simple cases, as grep can recurse itself (`grep -r`). Also, you *really* should always use `find -print0... xargs -0` when combining with `xargs`, otherwise funny filenames may (read: *will*) bite you.